# Pass stripe subscription data to payment request

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

I have a subscription setup where I'm using payment request button, currently I'm passing the amount in the payment request. I want to connect this to a subscription id from stripe.
I'm using react with stripe PaymentRequestButton.

here is the setup for the payment request I have setup.

```
 const pr = stripe.paymentRequest({
      currency: `${subscription.currency.toLowerCase()}`,
      country,
      total: {
        label: subscription.stripeSubscriptionId,
        amount: Math.round(subscription.monthlyCharge * 100),
      },
      requestPayerName: true,
      requestPayerEmail: true,
    });
```

I want to be able to remove the **total** and replace it with **subscription**

Or is there another payment request object for this scenario

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct support for subscriptions within the payment request API, no.

Instead, you can specify the amount to be charged then use the resulting payment method to [confirm the payment intent](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/payment-request-button?client=react#react-complete-payment) for the first invoice payment (similar to [this step in the guide](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/build-subscriptions?ui=elements&element=card#complete-payment)), otherwise you should [use the Payment Element to confirm the first payment](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/build-subscriptions?ui=elements&element=payment#add-the-payment-element-to-your-page) and present payment methods including wallets supported by the Payment Request Button.